# How to show Large Objects (LOB) contents?

Tags: postgresql, psql, blob

How could I get to have a look into LOB contents?

```
\d ticketgrantingticket

              Table "public.ticketgrantingticket"
          Column           |          Type          | Modifiers 
---------------------------+------------------------+-----------
id                         | character varying(765) | not null
number_of_times_used       | numeric(10,0)          | 
creation_time              | numeric(19,0)          | 
last_time_used             | numeric(19,0)          | 
previous_last_time_used    | numeric(19,0)          | 
ticketgrantingticket_id    | character varying(765) | 
expiration_policy          | oid                    | 
authentication             | oid                    | 
services_granted_access_to | oid                    | 
expired                    | boolean                | 
proxied_by                 | character varying(1)   | 
Indexes:
    "ticketgrantingticket_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)

SELECT expiration_policy, 
       authentication, 
       services_granted_access_to 
FROM ticketgrantingticket LIMIT 2;

 expiration_policy | authentication | services_granted_access_to 
-------------------+----------------+----------------------------
           1165742 |        1165743 |                    1165744
           1165757 |        1165758 |                    1165759
(2 rows)
```

This shows those numbers by default.

I so far found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14875748/1737973) which I think is not working properly in my client somehow:

```
SELECT expiration_policy, 
       encode(authentication::bytea, 'escape'),
       services_granted_access_to 
FROM ticketgrantingticket LIMIT 2;

ERROR:  cannot cast type oid to bytea
LINE 1: SELECT expiration_policy, encode(authentication::bytea, 'esc...
```

I can see the same in pgAdmin III.

I am expecting blobs there because IINM `oid` can be used as a large object reference. We are using `oid` because not knowing what we were doing. I have so far assessed that one of those three columns will be safely and profitably converted to `bytea`, but am being unable to spy the other two columns' contents in the source (non postgres) system, so I decide to spy them in this (postgres) target system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ran

```
SELECT expiration_policy, lo_get(authentication), services_granted_access_to 
FROM ticketgrantingticket
LIMIT 2;
```

after reading https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/lo-funcs.html suggested by a now defunct comment. That worked.

Comment: In PostgreSQL 10 this needs to be e.g. `lo_get(authentication::oid)`

Answer (score 5):

Because this question is nearing closure, I'll paste the links provided by  Andriy M and a few more.

- [Chapter 33. Large Objects](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/largeobjects.html), and [Server-side Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/lo-funcs.html), make note that the functions aren't all in the table. You'll have to read the page and the example to see how they work.
- [`lo`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/lo.html)

Large objects are kind of esoteric. They permit you to seek inside of them. Usually you build systems on top of them, like Raster support in PostGIS. As a side note, `psql` has some helpers.

```
\dl                    list large objects, same as \lo_list
\lo_export LOBOID FILE
\lo_import FILE [COMMENT]
\lo_list
\lo_unlink LOBOID      large object operations
```

Those are pretty much the functions available as client-side functions functions.